# Integrate CPT fields into Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I need help integrating Custom Post types into Woocommerce checkout page - I need to populate all the custom fields related to a CPT based on the selection made from the selct field - which populates CPT cars for the user logged in -

```
 woocommerce_form_field( 'car_sel', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => 'populate-cars',
    'label'         => __('Car for this Event'),
    'options' => my_acf_load_field( array($carname) ),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'car_sel' ));
function my_acf_load_field( $field )
 {

  get_currentuserinfo();
$id = get_current_user_id();

$args = array(
    'author'       => $id,
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'post_title',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'post_type'        => 'car',
    'post_status'      => 'publish' );

$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $carname[$post->post_title] = $post->post_title;

}


// Important: return the field
return $carname;

}
```

Now I need to populate fields like make, model & cc into Woocommerce field and pass them onto the email - I also want to change the variables depending on the select - So I need onchange functionality

Can anyone help me?  Struggling to get meta values based on post title - nothing seems to be working :(

Answer (score 0):

I have written very extensively about [customizing the WooCommerce checkout](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/). Here's the first part (displaying the form field on the checkout adapted to your select options. Depending on if you start getting really long lists of cars, you may want to look into the [Transient API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache the `$posts` values. Also for reference, [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) is awesome.

```
function kia_get_car_names_checkout_options(){

    $args = array(
        'author'           => get_current_user_id(),
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'post_title',
        'order'            => 'ASC',
        'post_type'        => 'car',
        'post_status'      => 'publish' );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    $car_names = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'post_title', 'ID' ); 

    return $car_names;
}

// Add a new checkout field
function kia_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
            'another_field' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => kia_get_car_names_checkout_options(),
                'required'      => true,
                'label' => __( 'Another field' )
                )
            );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'kia_filter_checkout_fields' );


// display the extra field on the checkout form
function kia_extra_checkout_fields(){

    $checkout = WC()->checkout(); ?>

    <div class="extra-fields">
    <h3><?php _e( 'Additional Fields' ); ?></h3>

    <?php 
    // because of this foreach, everything added to the array in the previous function will display automagically
    foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['extra_fields'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ,'kia_extra_checkout_fields' );
```

Comment: Sure. If this worked, then you should "accept" this as the answer.

Comment: only one slight problem - It's storing the value as in the ID of the car fields for all - Is that any easy way to store the option text for the drop down rather than the value?

Comment: my code -     <select name="make_field" id="my_car_select_child1" class="select " placeholder="">
       <option value="572">Seat</option><option value="488">Ford</option><option value="499">VW</option>
      </select>

Comment: I need the text not the value to be stored in woocommerce order - as in "Ford" not the ID of the car, I can't hard code it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Storing the ID seems like a better option to me. Then no matter what the names may change to in the future you will always have the right data. You can always pull the name from the ID, but not always the inverse.

Comment: it would be easier though if the correct data was in the order though as the order is for an event / race and I need to pull all field information for different races - searched and tried jquery but nothing works - any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's still the correct data. And you can pull the post title/name from the saved ID at any time and display it anywhere (in orders, emails, whatevers). See [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title). I don't really know what you are doing, so you will need to ask a new question and give the relevant details.

Comment: hey I have a major problem now which I just noticed.  When I go to change any other drop down the other drop downs are reset - this is on the checkout page where there is credit card drop downs and they can be set due to the code - please help